# I am trying to push values from an object inside an array

Tags: javascript, json, object, push

I am trying to push data coming from an array of objects (key/value), then pushing it inside an array, to display them later.

I have already tried doing the push inside the array but till now it is always giving undefined for the total amount of items being pushed.

```
//array
var clients_array = '[{"code": "1", "name": "client 1"}, 
{"code": "2", "name": "client 2"}, {"code": "3", "name": "client 3"}]';

var displayClient = [];

var json_parse1 = JSON.parse(clients_array);
json_parse1.forEach(function(client){
    console.log(client.code + ' - ' + client.name);
    displayClient.push(client.code + ' - ' + client.name);
    alert(displayClient[i]);
})
```

Using the above code, In the console.log I am getting the correct data which I would like to push. But when alerting the displayClient array, which in this case should be filled with the console.logged data, it displays undefined for each data. Hence, I would like to push the correct data as displayed in the console.log.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a parameter for `i` in the callback function.

```
json_parse1.forEach(function (client, i) {
                                      ^
```

```js
var clients_array = '[{"code": "1", "name": "client 1"}, {"code": "2", "name": "client 2"}, {"code": "3", "name": "client 3"}]';

var displayClient = [];

var json_parse1 = JSON.parse(clients_array);
json_parse1.forEach(function (client, i) {
    console.log(client.code + ' - ' + client.name);
    displayClient.push(client.code + ' - ' + client.name);
    alert(displayClient[i]);
})

console.log(displayClient);
```

A better approach would be to use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and return the new items.

```js
var array = [{ code: "1", name: "client 1" }, { code: "2", name: "client 2" }, { code: "3", name: "client 3" }],
    displayClient = array.map(({ code, name }) => [code, name].join(' - '));

console.log(displayClient);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, you are so right. That solved my problem :D